# How do I make documents opened with Storage Access Framework appear in Recents?

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I call `createChooser()` with `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. How can I make this document appear in the 'Recents' list in the SAF chooser? The documentation only mentions the recents list in the context of creating documents. I want files opened in my app (created in another app) to appear here.

Comment: `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is not part of the Storage Access Framework. `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` are. Beyond that, AFAIK, the decision of whether or not something goes in the recents list is up to the storage provider, not the client.

Comment: @CommonsWare Many devices display the SAF chooser with this, why is that?

Comment: If there are no other `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` implementations, I can see this UI coming up by default. But, if there are other `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` implementations that otherwise support your `Intent` (e.g., MIME type), I would expect a chooser first.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok I will use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT on Android 4.4 and higher, since that's what I most wanted anyway. However the question still remains.

Comment: Again, AFAIK, what you want (*you* control whether the document goes in recents) is not possible. The storage provider decides that.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, sorry I missed that. It seems a bit odd though - sser picks a document in the SAF, and there is a list of Recents, but it can't include the recent documents that they opened.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117553/discussion-between-steve-m-and-commonsware).